# Installing Mayavi : UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character

Tags: python, windows, unicode, anaconda, mayavi

I am trying to install Mayavi on a Windows computer using Anaconda 3.6.

Unfortunately, I get an error I do not understand. I am still discovering Python.

I have already looked at other similar problems on the Internet but cannot find anything working.

Could you please help me ?

```
(C:\Anaconda) C:\Windows\system32>pip install mayavi --upgrade
Collecting mayavi
  Using cached mayavi-4.5.0.tar.bz2
Requirement already up-to-date: apptools in c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from
mayavi)
Requirement already up-to-date: traits in c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from ma
yavi)
Requirement already up-to-date: traitsui in c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from
mayavi)
Requirement already up-to-date: configobj in c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from
 apptools->mayavi)
Requirement already up-to-date: pyface in c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from tr
aitsui->mayavi)
Requirement already up-to-date: six in c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from confi
gobj->apptools->mayavi)
Requirement already up-to-date: pygments in c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from
pyface->traitsui->mayavi)
Building wheels for collected packages: mayavi
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for mayavi ... error
  Complete output from command C:\Anaconda\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools,
tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Fuentes\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-ybqsb6ne\
\mayavi\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().rep
lace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel
-d C:\Users\Fuentes\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpielgp53opip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Building TVTK classes... vtkContextDevice2D: Ignoring method: Get/SetViewportR
ect
```

[...]

```
    File "C:\Users\Fuentes\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ybqsb6ne\mayavi\tvtk\wra
pper_gen.py", line 243, in generate_code
      self._gen_class_init(node, out)
    File "C:\Users\Fuentes\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ybqsb6ne\mayavi\tvtk\wra
pper_gen.py", line 315, in _gen_class_init
      self.dm.write_class_doc(klass.__doc__, out, indent)
    File "C:\Users\Fuentes\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ybqsb6ne\mayavi\tvtk\ind
enter.py", line 169, in write_class_doc
      out.write(indent.format('\n' + ret))
    File "C:\Anaconda\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
      return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
  **UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2264' in positio
n 3665: character maps to <undefined>**

  ----------------------------------------
  **Failed building wheel for mayavi**
  Running setup.py clean for mayavi
**Failed to build mayavi**
Installing collected packages: mayavi
  Running setup.py install for mayavi ... error
```

[...]

```
      File "C:\Anaconda\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
        return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
    **UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2264' in posit
ion 3665: character maps to <undefined>**

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Anaconda\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\
\Users\\Fuentes\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-ybqsb6ne\\mayavi\\setup.py';f=g
etattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.c
lose();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Fuentes\
AppData\Local\Temp\pip-vjpz5i0u-record\install-record.txt --single-version-exter
nally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Fuentes\AppData\Lo
cal\Temp\pip-build-ybqsb6ne\mayavi\
```

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem. My solution is that download 'mayavi‑4.5.0+vtk81‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl' from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/  and pip install mayavi‑4.5.0+vtk81‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl directly.

Comment: Please, add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. See [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I managed installing *mayavi*, but I did not solve the problem : I just uninstalled Anaconda 3.6 and installed Anaconda 2.7 instead. Then I could install everything I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and managed to override it by downloading the mayavi-4.5.0.zip file at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mayavi and copy pasting the "mayavi" folder directly to Anaconda3\Lib